# Starting using Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I would start to use Java EE for working purpose but I really don't know where to start with this technology so big. What could I try initially?

Comment: The term J2EE was used for Java Enterprise editions *before* Java EE 5 (which was introduced in 2006). So from this perspective J2EE can really be considered as dinosaur. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How good are you in core java? If you are really good in core java, you can start Java EE by refering the below mentioned links with servlets and JSP

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/index.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with java `Servlet` and `JSP's` examples and deploy it in [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) .

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I would actually not start with jsp's and servlets, but rather with j2se and how to program in java. If you feel comfortable doing that, then you can look further.

Answer (score 0):

JSP and Servlets. Setup a Server (probably tomcat) and try learning JSP and Servlets